# Doing a tf lookupTransform without publishing a specific transform?

Tags: ros, ar-kinect, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps this is not the best title for my question, so let me briefly explain a situation.

I have a system where there is an ARTag which I am detecting from the camera using ar_kinect. I know this ARTag's location in the environment, which is published by another transform. (Lets say /world -> /ARTag_Actual). The ar_kinect package publishes a transform of where it sees the tag (/kinect -> /ARTag_Percieved) So from this, we should be able to simply calculate the transform from /world to /kinect by publishing an identity transform from /ARTag_Actual to /ARTag_Percieved but I want to be able to instead calculate this, and then simply publish a transform directly from /world to /kinect. How do I go about doing this? Should I just be using the bullet library directly?  I apologize as I am not very experienced using the tf library.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11584/doing-a-tf-lookuptransform-without-publishing-a-specific-transform?/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to compute an arbitrary transform you should use the linear math library of your choice.  The one used in the tf API is the bullet one, and can be used directly for chaining transforms together to compute the net transform.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0